# Importing html into MS Office then saving as docx loses footer

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, office365, html, docx

I have the following simplified html which contains some MS specific tags to add a header and footer to each page of the document if the file is opened in Word. This seems to display when I open the file in Word (although I do get a square icon next to the header that is usually seen for unsupported unicode and similar).

However if I then go to save the file as docx, and then reopen that new file, the header and footer do not display.

I am testing with a local installation of Office 365 for Business (installed a couple of weeks ago version 16.0.14527.20276)

Any ideas why this happens? If I get rid of the table tag and associated tbody, tr, td tags, then the problem goes away. But a lot of posts online (searching for `hrdftrtbl` - the id of the table) all seem to have the similar html to try and coerce word into not putting the header in the wrong place, or repeating it more than it should etc. Has something changed in newer versions of word recently to change the recommended way of  doing this? The html I am trying to work with is quite old and I don't have older versions of word to test with.

```
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <xml>
    <w:WordDocument>
    <w:View>Print</w:View>
    <w:Zoom>90</w:Zoom>
    <w:DoNotOptimizeForBrowser/>
    </w:WordDocument>
    </xml>
    <![endif]-->

    <style>
      p.MsoFooter, li.MsoFooter, div.MsoFooter {
        margin:0in;
        margin-bottom:.0001pt;
        mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
        tab-stops:center 3.0in right 6.0in;
        font-size:12.0pt;
      }

      @page Section1 {
        size:8.5in 11.0in;
        margin:1.0in 1.25in 1.0in 1.25in ;
        mso-header-margin:.5in;
        mso-header:h1;
        mso-footer: f1;
        mso-footer-margin:.5in;
      }

      div.Section1 {
        page:Section1;
      }

      table#hrdftrtbl {
        margin:0in 0in 0in 9in;
      }
    </style>

    <title>hi</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="Section1">
      <div align="center">
        <strong>TEST DOCUMENT</strong>
      </div>
      <h1>section 1</h1>
      hello

      <h1>section 2</h1>
      there

    </div>
    <table id="hrdftrtbl">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div style="mso-element:header" id="h1">
              <div class="MsoHeader">myheader</div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div style="mso-element:footer" id="f1">
              <div class="MsoFooter">myfooter</div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could it be that saving the header and footer in a single table causes an issue? In my brief test, they show up together as two adjacent footers. Is that the intent?

Comment: I only see one footer. The intent is just a single header at the top of each page and single footer at the bottom of each page. I don't think a single table is the problem because if I split it out so the header is in one table and the footer in another (changing the id to a class and modifying the css accordingly) I still have the issue of the header/footer disappearing if I save the file as a docx and reopen.

I'm not really sure why a table is used at all really, but lots of posts online all do it the same way with an id of `hrdftrtbl` and I'm not sure what may break by diverging from it.